# IE11 crashes when clicking on select - dropdown options (randomly)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, select, internet-explorer-11

I have several users trying to submit a webform. But i'm getting reports that when they click on a select dropdown menu or start to scroll through the options it causing the browser to crash - Internet explorer has stopped responding. The user then refreshes the page to try again but then faced with the same issue.

This is only related to IE 11 and this happens randomly - sometimes the select option works and then they click on another select and it crashes again.

```
IE11 version: 11.648.17134.0

Windows 10

jquery-3.3.1.min.js
```

Please bear in mind some users will not have access rights to their browser settings.

Here a simple select menu:

```
 <select name="test" id="test">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
 </select>
```

I read that adding a resize option to the list to 0 or 1 might resolve this issue. So i added a jquery to modify them all onload:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 setTimeout(
  function() 
   {
    $("select").attr("size", "1")
   }, 10);
 });
```

But this didn't help

Comment: I made a test with IE 11 in Windows 10 and looks like your code is working without crashing the browser. I want to confirm with you whether you are able to produce the issue on your machine or not? If yes, did you notice any error or warning message? It can help to narrow down the issue. Also check if this issue start occurring after any specific update for Win 10.

Comment: I did it on my machine and was able to reproduce the issue. I loaded up the task manager and the console within the browser and all looks normal.

Comment: I still have doubt that your IE get crash due to any other reason and not because of HTML select option dropdown control. Try to reset your Internet Explorer and check whether it helps to resolve the issue or not. Ref: https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings